# Disabling g++'s return-value optimisation

Tags: c++, optimization, compiler-construction, g++, return-value-optimization

What flag(s) do I need on the command line to disable the return-value optimisation automatically enabled by the g++ compiler?

Comment: Give an example of code, and why you don't want this kind of optimization

Comment: @fge I am debugging and testing the implementation of my software library so I would prefer to see every single step throughout the course of the execution of my software...

Comment: Of course, you do realize that many people will actually use your library with constructor elision, so you need to test it in that configuration too ?

Comment: @Matthieu M, thanks for your reminding.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

`-fno-elide-constructors`

> The C++ standard allows an implementation to omit creating a temporary which is only used to initialize another object of the same type.  Specifying this option disables that optimization, and forces G++ to call the copy constructor in all cases. [Source: man gcc]
>
> ---

Comment: Off topic: it might save someone some time to note that clang [my --version is Apple clang version 4.1 (tags/Apple/clang-421.11.66) (based on LLVM 3.1svn)] has a bug when using this flag, which in my case seems to produce seg faults : http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=12208