# Temporary objects with -fno-elide-constructors

Tags: c++, gcc, clang

I am interested in the correct semantics of C++ when the -fno-elide-constructors option is used with clang or gcc, and an object is being returned by value.  If I have this function and call it:

```
X foo()
{
    X x(0);
    X y(1);
    X z;
    if (rand() > 50)
        z = x;
    else
        z = y;
    return z;
}

X z = foo();
```

then I can see that the copy constructor of X is called only once.  However, if I modify the function slightly like so:

```
X foo()
{
    X x(0);
    X y(1);
    if (rand() > 50)
        return x;
    else
        return y;
}

X z = foo();
```

then the copy constructor is called twice.  I can see how this might necessary in the latter case from an implementation perspective but what I find confusing is that it seems that *even when we explicitly switch off copy elision* there are different numbers of copy constructors being called depending on how the function is implemented.

Is there a section of the standard which covers this behaviour?

Comment: I'm not getting the same results you are. [Here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/983f5afff112991c), it shows that both forms call the copy constructor twice.

Comment: Please add compiler specific tags, as this is mainly about your particukar compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first case you see [return value optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization), that basically means the compiler allocates `z` in the return-slot of the function.  This won't work in the second case, so you see another copy there.  Copy elision is something different: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision and does not apply here.  The standard just says something like *the compiler is free to omit unnecessary copies* which allows but does not require either of those optimizations.

Comment: Thanks that clarifies things a bit for me, although this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8758152/disabling-gs-return-value-optimisation seems to imply that the option should switch of RVO as well.