# C++ Object Initialization (Stack)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I saw today a c++ Initialization of a class which I am not familiar with.

```
CPrice price = CPrice();
```

The Initialization should normally look like this

```
CPrice price;
```

I would have guessed that the first one should throw an error or something.
What happens here ? I would guess that the variable is on the stack because it wasn't initialized with `new` .

I use Visual studio express 2012 with microsofts c++ compiler. Is it maybe something which is microsoft compiler specific and thus allowed ?

Comment: I would think they are following some sort of style guide.  If you have an `= ` when you create a variable you know it is initialized.

Comment: Why do you think this should produce an error? `CPrice()` is a constructor that returns an object that is assigned to the freshly declared variable...

Comment: @tobi303 Is it assigned with the = or is it copied ( "operator=" )?

Comment: This is an initialisation; there is no assignment here.

Comment: @Bongo Nope, actually in the context of variable declaration `=` means copy. `CPrice price = CPrice();` and `CPrice price(CPrice());` are the same by definition. Welcome to c++ syntax quirks.

Comment: The first initialization is safer if you are not absolutely sure `CPrice` is a user type (perhaps you are writing template code for example, or someone has done `using CPrice = int`) because otherwise `price` may be uninitialized.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Both lines are perfectly fine, and end up with the same observable behaviour from the client code point of view: `price` is a default constructed variable of type `CPrice`, of course allocated on the stack.

---

If you want to go into the technicalities, they are not identical:

`CPrice price;` is a default initialization of a variable `price` of type `CPrice`. This is a user type (i.e., a class), so it always mean a call to the default constructor.

`CPrice price = CPrice();` is a compound expression that does two things:

- `CPrice()`: initializes and anonymous `CPrice` object (on the stack), by direct initialization (it invokes a constructor with the `()`). Since the parentheses are empty, this will call the default constructor.
- It then copy initializes (before C++11) / move initializes (available to C++11 onward) a variable `price` of type `CPrice`, the copied-from/moved-from object being the anonymous `CPrice` instance.

The longest allocation forces that a copy constructor exists for `CPrice`, or the code will be in error. But **the compiler is allowed to skip the copy construction and optimise it away**, by issuing the same code than with the shortest form.
Additionally, in C++11, if a move constructor exists for `CPrice`, it will be used in place of the copy constructor in this case (that is, if this operation is not entirely removed anyway).

So the only perceivable difference is that the shortest form will compile even if `CPrice` is not copy constructible. Both forms require `CPrice` to be default constructible.

---

One more more or less related precision, coming from the other answer. You could think that an *hypothetical* middle ground declaration like this would be the same:

```
CPrice price();
```

Yet, it is actually completely different: this one declares `price` to be a function taking no argument (the empty parentheses), and returning a `CPrice`. It is colloquially known as the *most vexing parse*.

Comment: More than likely the copy will be elided and it will be the same as the second example.

Comment: @NathanOliver Even if the copy is elided (which I agree it almost certainly will be) the relevant copy constructor must exist and be callable, so it's not quite the same.

Comment: Thank you for your comments ! @NathanOliver: I guess we were writing it at the same time ; )

Comment: @AlanStokes Yeah I forgot it is not using the assignment operator as this is direct initialization and that uses the copy constructor.

Comment: In C++11, `CPrice price = CPrice();` `price` may be move constructed, see [here how move constructor is generated by default](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4819936/why-no-default-move-assignment-move-constructor).

Comment: @Allanqunzi Thank you for this important remark ! I updated the answer.

Comment: There's a great Herb Sutter GOTW article on this. You've covered pretty much everything he mentions there, though its still worth a read for anyone confused on this topic: http://herbsutter.com/2013/05/09/gotw-1-solution/

Answer (score -1):

the assignation is calling the assignment operator (if not deleted) when the instance has already been declared . The first line declares AND explicitly calls a constructor , not really helpful on stack but more in the heap with polymorphism .
The second line calls directly its default constructor (if not deleted and if no operator() implemented too )

If you still wonder for the operator = , then explicitly declare in the class declaration
`CPrice & operator = (const CPrice &) = delete;`

Comment: _" heap with polymorphism"_ What has storage of an instance to do with polymorphism??

Answer (score -2):

The two lines do exactly the same thing. They both call the default constructor (one with no arguments). Also valid could have been `CPrice price();`, as this and the first one you have allow you to push arguments if there is a constructor that takes them, whilst your second one would not. Also yes, if the new keyword is not used, then the allocation is on the stack (for simple things like this).

Comment: what do you mean with "simple things like this"?

Comment: Just simple object creation. It seems to me that there's three ways of doing everything in C++ so I was largely covering my back in case someone came along and told me that new wasn't the only way to make new objects on the heap.

Comment: `CPrice price();` doesn't do what you think it does: it's a declaration of a function called `price` which takes no arguments an returns a `CPrice` object. See article on [most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse).

Comment: @NikBougalis hehe, [classic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse) ; )

Comment: *"The two lines do exactly the same thing."* No they don't. They have different meanings, although compiler is allowed to optimized the second, to be *effectively* the same. `CPrice price = CPrice();` and `CPrice price(CPrice());` are the same by definition, `CPrice price;` is different in principle.

Comment: Well in that case I've learned something new for today. Am I right in thinking that the very end results are identical though?

Comment: It depends. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8758152/disabling-gs-return-value-optimisation, You can play with http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ffe96f2e68c5a2c0. This option doesn't make the compiler bend the rules. Both program and outputs are equally valid. As opposed to e.g `-ffast-math`.